# how to start server using java?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

i am using Rabbitmq server.can i start server using Java code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can start Rabbitmq from the command line, you can start it from Java using 
`System.exec("cmd /c ...");` where `...` is the command you used to launch Rabbitmq.